# MVVM Datagrid ComboBox DataSource not Updating on Selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid in an MVVM project which has two ComboBox columns. I have a DataTable as it's ItemsSource, as well as an ObservableObject Collection as the source of the ComboBox items. There is an instance of the ObservableObject for Selected Item.

While I am able to drop down and select the items in the boxes, my problem is when an item is selected it is not updating the DataTable records with that selection. Example if in a record I want to set a column to "Computer" in the ComboBox, looking at the value in that record later it shows as an empty cell instead of Computer.

What am I doing wrong in terms of binding the SelectedItem and then updating the underlying DataTable with that new selection and new record?

```
    public class AddGroupObjectTypeModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Properties
        private int iD;
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return iD;
            }
            set
            {
                if (iD != value)
                {
                    iD = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private string objType;
        public string ObjType
        {
            get
            {
                return objType;
            }
            set
            {
                if (objType != value)
                {
                    objType = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

```
        private readonly ObservableCollection<AddGroupObjectTypeModel> objectTypeTerms = new()
        {
            new AddGroupObjectTypeModel { ID = 1, ObjType = "User" },
            new AddGroupObjectTypeModel { ID = 2, ObjType = "Group" },
            new AddGroupObjectTypeModel { ID = 3, ObjType = "Computer" }
        };

        public IEnumerable<AddGroupObjectTypeModel> ObjectTypeTerms
        {
            get { return objectTypeTerms; }
        }

        private AddGroupObjectTypeModel selectedObjectTypeTerm = new();
        public AddGroupObjectTypeModel SelectedObjectTypeTerm
        {
            get { return selectedObjectTypeTerm; }
            set { selectedObjectTypeTerm = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private DataTable objectsDisplayTable;
        public DataTable ObjectsDisplayTable
        {
            get { return objectsDisplayTable; }
            set { objectsDisplayTable = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

            ObjectsDisplayTable = new("Temporary Table");
            ObjectsDisplayTable.Columns.Add("ObjectName", typeof(String));
            ObjectsDisplayTable.Columns.Add("OType", typeof(String));
            ObjectsDisplayTable.Columns.Add("ODomain", typeof(String));
```

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="ObjectsTable"
                                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                                          Margin="2,0,0,0" 
                                          Style="{StaticResource ThemedDataGrid}"
                                          BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsDisplayTable,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          CanUserAddRows="True"
                                          SelectionMode="Single"
                                          SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                                          >

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type"
                                                        x:Name="OType"
                                                        MinWidth="200"
                                                        >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ObjectTypeTerms, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                      DisplayMemberPath="ObjType"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedObjectTypeTerm.ObjType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedObjectTypeTerm.ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                      SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                                      SelectedIndex="0"
                                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false"
                                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTheme}"
                                                       />
                                        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Which column of the `DataTable` are you trying to update?

Comment: DataTable has a column for the above ObjectType. There is a drop down combo box that allows a selection. End goal is user enters however many records, selecting possibly different items for each records ComboBox. A button gets pressed, and I then want to retrieve a datatable of the datagrid with those values in the Object field. 

In the "OType" DataColumn above in the Xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to the column of the `DataTable` that you want to update:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ObjectTypeTerms, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ObjType"
          SelectedValuePath="ObjType"
          SelectedValue="{Binding OType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTheme}" />
```

It makes no sense to bind to both `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks I have been wrestling with what I was doing wrong for days. It was setting SelectedValue to the Column Name, alongside the UpdateSourceTrigger, fixed it.